# Leak issue, downstairs neighbor

Tags: ceiling, leak

I think I posted this in the wrong place initially.

I am having an issue with my downstairs neighbor. The neighbor has a damaged leaking ceiling with brownish color (might be an issue from a long time) and is saying that the wet ceiling was observed just a few days ago. We have had heavy rain pouring over the past few days. The neighbor continues insisting that it is my fault even though I do not have a leak on my end. I contacted the property management right away and called a plumber. He came in and inspected my 2 bathrooms and found NO leak. He suggested it might be an issue with the roof or the ventilation but I still provided my insurance to the neighbor. I communicated this to the association but now he doesn’t believe my plumber’s inspection and he personally is making an accusation that this issue is from my unit. I find this not acceptable because the property manager is not a plumber but he has these demands and tells me that the plumber needs to remove my toilet and take a look. Why would they come in and mess with my toilet if it turns out it is not actually the toilet but the roof instead? Let me know what you think but I believe they should cut into my neighbors ceiling and figure out the source of the leak and if it is my toilet okay go ahead and fix it. Especially when I already provided my insurance

Comment: This is probably not the right place either.  We deal mainly with fixing problems of a DIY type.  The place of the leak will need to be found before we can begin.  Even then this is mainly for owned homes, since multi-family dwellings usually need licensed contractors.  There might be a local tenants/condos group/association or city hall that might help with the local regulations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because unfortunately, this sounds like more of a legal issue than a DIY issue. You should carefully read your lease to see what your responsibilities and rights are in this situation. I hate to say it, but you may need to consider getting some legal representation.

Comment: Removing a toilet to check for a leak is an order of magnitude easier operation than cutting a hole in (and subsequently repairing) a ceiling.

Comment: I will need to agree with @FreeMan.  Too many(maybe fake) stories online that getting a  lawyer early would help.  Having your plumber's report contested is one reason.

Comment: Why do you think this is a fake story?

Comment: In most cases, this is the building manager's problem, not yours. They may need and ard entitled to access to your unit to diagnose the problem ... Unless you are in an upstairs)downstairs condo with no building manager, in which case you and the neighbor need to cooperate to find and fix the problem because it's damaging both of your investments.

Answer (score 3):

Neither you nor your downstairs neighbor is right, because nobody knows where the leak is coming from. It could very well be your toilet (albeit unlikely), or the roof. The thing with leaks is that water travels, so you could be having a leak, then it showing up in your neighbor's ceiling several feet away from the source. Or it could have nothing to do with you. The poor guy downstairs is having his ceiling destroyed by a leak, so let him send someone to check your toilet for Pete's sake. Either the leak is coming from your place or it's not, so it's not like checking your place will increase your liability. Giving him your insurance information does not stop the leak. If it's not your toilet, then they'll have to break through his ceiling and trace it.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be occupying the same building as another person.  Take it from Ukraine and Russia: The first law of being neighbors is **don't be a selfish jerk**.

You are saying "I don't want ANY intrusion into my home, I deny everything, they must go to extremes to prove their claim, not my problem until they prove it". That can backfire on you two ways.

First, when at great expense they tear up their ceilings to find **that it is your fault after all**, you will need to pay for **all** that.   When you argue "But I shouldn't have to pay for heavy ceiling repair when it could've been fixed by changing a $5 wax ring on my toilet", the court will laugh at you, saying *you were given that opportunity* and you refused it.

And second, you'll have to live everyday with a neighbor who hates your guts.  And I know that sounds like a small price to pay *right now* for the prospect of not having plumbers trudging through your home, but try living with the consequences for 5++ more years when you can't ask that person for anything, and have to suffer either direct retaliation, or always wondering if that thing that happened was them being passive-aggressive.  Creating such hostility is extremely short-sighted - easy to do but hard to live with.

Put up with the mild intrusion - it's part of living in a community. *If you don't want to live in a community, get a single-family home farther out that you can afford, and make sure it's **not** in an HOA*.

The right answer is "Sure bro, it's probably not me, but of course I'll help you out. I'm sure you'd do the same for me if the situation was reversed."

Comment: What are you talking about? Court? Who mentioned anything about court over a leak? I was just basically asking what do you think the steps are to resolve this issue. Since the ceiling downstairs is already messed up, it makes more sense to cut it and see if it even leaks from my toilet. If the issue is my toilet, I will cover the expenses yes

Comment: @abc123 Hope for the best, but plan for the worst.  Thinking about how it would go in court is also illustrative to what the right thing is.   Since you are not a plumber you do not actually know the best answer.  But your strong reluctance about having your pipes examined creates the risk of "confirmation bias" in your imagination of the best solution.  I would leave such things to the professionals. But mostly, don't let the matter come between you and a neighbor.

Comment: These days, wouldn't one just drill/poke a small hole in the damaged area of the neighbor's ceiling and run an endoscope camera up there to see what's going on?  No big new damage to fix, and photos showing exactly where the liquid is coming from.